# How to get cookies from web-browser with Python?

Tags: python, cookies, openid, browser

**Context:**
*I am working on a backend access to an OpenID consumer (StackExchange in fact). If I am to provide all possible OpenID providers as an option to the user, then I'd have to simulate browser interaction to authenticate to each of these providers before I could submit the Open ID URL. However, I think I could cut this short by accessing the existing cookies of the user's web-browser, and requesting authentication to the consumer directly with the URL.*

**Problem:**
How to access the user's web-browser's cookies? I've seen very little information on how to do it with Python. This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537592/how-to-extract-firefox-session-cookie-python-language-preferred) partly answers the problem regarding Firefox, pointing especially to [the code sample](http://blog.mithis.net/archives/python/90-firefox3-cookies-in-python) her below. However, I would need to access cookies from the most common web browsers used on Linux, not just Firefox.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# Protocol implementation for handling gsocmentors.com transactions
# Author: Noah Fontes nfontes AT cynigram DOT com
# License: MIT

def sqlite2cookie(filename):
    from cStringIO import StringIO
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite

    con = sqlite.connect(filename)

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select host, path, isSecure, expiry, name, value from moz_cookies")

    ftstr = ["FALSE","TRUE"]

    s = StringIO()
    s.write("""\
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.
""")
    for item in cur.fetchall():
        s.write("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (
            item[0], ftstr[item[0].startswith('.')], item[1],
            ftstr[item[2]], item[3], item[4], item[5]))

    s.seek(0)

    cookie_jar = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar()
    cookie_jar._really_load(s, '', True, True)
    return cookie_jar
```

**Question: Does Python provide a module that can facilitate cookie extraction from web-browsers?** Otherwise, how should I adapt the above code to draw cookies from other browsers, like Chromium etc.?

*PS: Or am I looking at the initial problem (i.e. authenticate to the OpenID provider) the wrong way? (I feel I am just replacing a problem by another.)*

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634408/can-non-web-applications-use-openid

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921532/retrieving-cookies-python

Comment: @monkut: actually that one is only relevant to keep cookies throughout sessions, which I already know how to do. What I am trying to do is to get cookies from the browser's itself.

Comment: you might want to look at the Cookie module for retrieving cookies.          thiscookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
        if u'HTTP_COOKIE' in os.environ.keys():
            thiscookie.load(os.environ[u'HTTP_COOKIE'])

Comment: @monkut: the interesting part here is the `HTTP_COOKIE` in `os.environ.keys()`, do you have more info somewhere about that? Thanks.

Comment: I imagine this is populated by wsgi or cgi for when incoming requests call your script.

Answer (score 35):

I created a module to do exactly that, available here: https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/browsercookie/

Example usage:

```
import requests
import browsercookie
cj = browsercookie.chrome()
r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com', cookies=cj)
```

**python3 fork:** https://github.com/borisbabic/browser_cookie3

Comment: Link is updated. Also available using `pip install browsercookie`.

Comment: Note to others coming across this post now: The module does not support current Chrome versions.

Comment: The python 2 version (https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/browsercookie/) works fine for me in the latest Chrome (57)

Comment: Recent versions of chrome changed the way to encrypt cookies. Hopefully someone will figure it out and send a patch.

Answer (score 0):

Besides browser-cookie3, you can try https://github.com/n8henrie/pycookiecheat -- it worked for me with Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04 as of April 2021.