# Python request and real-time session

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm automating one website with python request and I've got one problem. My requests work fine - log in to the page etc. However... Once I'm logged to my account, any other login attempt will kick me out. So basically when I'm logged in chrome and send the POST, then it kicks me out from the chrome. Is there any way to merge python request with browser so after refresh I will be logged in ? I could do it with js and ajax calls but in this case I need python solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to use Chrome cookies in requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729726/python-how-to-use-chrome-cookies-in-requests)

Comment: @smoggers looks good but I'm still encountering the problem