# How to get url with specifed browser?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

this my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Url = "https://gmail.com"
R = requests.get(Url)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(R.text,"lxml")
print(Soup)
```

But i need my cookies, login datas and other things and they are stored in google chrome so i want getting url via google chrome.

Path of Google Chrome: "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

is that possible? Thanks...

Comment: If you want to open a url using a browser... use a brower. If you want to open a browser with a given url, call it like "path_to_chrome_exe url"... But If you want to use requests with chrome cookies, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729726/python-how-to-use-chrome-cookies-in-requests)

Comment: @Sr.S Hmm So how i can do it on this code? actually i have other ideas.

Comment: Please, take a look at the url I posted. There are some examples.

Comment: @Sr.S Thanks but they are not for this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you must use selenium, download the chrome webdriver
`options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

driver_path= 'C:\Users\your_user_here\Downloads\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=options)`

Comment: Thanks worked but Is there any other way to  web scraping with my own chrome.exe?