# How to get cookies from all users web-browser with Python?

Tags: python, cookies, browser, openid

This question is a extension from [How to get cookies from web-browser with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812420/how-to-get-cookies-from-web-browser-with-python)

I would like to extract cookies from the same url for 3 accounts logged into chrome. I've already done the code test from the previous url and it returns me only cookies from a single user. I have already researched the library and apparently does not have this functionality.

That is the code i'm using:

```py
import browser_cookie3
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/pedro/Desktop/chromedriver')
cookies = browser_cookie3.chrome(domain_name='my/url')
print('cookies._cookies')
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `selenium` module. You are able to run Chrome (in selenium named a webdriver) from Python.

If you start the Chrome browser with selenium (and store it into a variable), you have the selenium webdriver and you are able to log in as you would normally do.

Then `cookies = driver.get_cookies()` leads to cookies being a dictionary, ready to use.

[Reference](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)